# Is there any way to orbit around the object instead of a 3D cursor?

Tags: navigation

I would like to know if there is a way to orbit my viewport around a selected object in Blender, instead of orbiting around the 3D cursor, without having to manually set the 3D cursor to the object pivot point, similar to how it works in Maya.

Edit: Thank you for all the answers! I just figured it out. I checked the "lock to 3D cursor" on my viewport pannel. It is fine when I uncheck it.

Answer (score 4):

In the *Preferences > Navigation > Orbit & Pan >* enable *Orbit Around Selection*:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can press the Numpad period button to set the orbit to the currently selected object.

In the keymap, it's under 3D View > Frame Selected [image]